# An inequality for $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

Why $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{8}+\dfrac{1}{10}\leq\displaystyle\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x$ ?

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{8}+\frac{1}{10}<\frac{1}{\pi}=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{\pi}dx<\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$